# Getting IdentityFramework, IDesignTimeDbContextFactory, .NetCore 2.1, and DbContext to play nice together

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have an existing .Net core project where I have the DBContext broken out into it's own library. In this project I use IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to create the DbContext for the class library. This allows me to use commands like add-migration and update-database despite the fact that there is no actual appsettings.json or app.config file to pull the connection string from.

The problem I have now is that I would like to do the same thing, only this time add in IdentityFramework. From what I can read online it looks like the standard way to do this is to abandon plain old DbContext and make everything inherit from IdentityDbContext. This seems to be OK right up until the point where I try to add the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory. IDesignTimeDbContextFactory expects DBContext and cannot use IdentityDbContext.

How can I have a class library that supports IdentityFramework and IDesignTimeDbContextFactory? Anyone have an example?

My Project Structure is:
.Web
.Api
.Models (Contains the Identity Models)

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
}


public class AppRole : IdentityRole
{
    public AppRole() : base() { }
    public AppRole(string name) : base(name) { }
}
```

.Service (Contains the DbContext and Identity Framework)

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
     public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
     {
     }

     public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
     {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
     }
 }
```

**DBContextFactory** *(Does not like ApplicationDbContext)*

```
public class DBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=IdentityFrameWork;AttachDBFilename=IdentityFramework.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");

    }
}
```

I need a working example of .Net Core and Identity framework in a separate .Net Standard class. Can anyone help me out?

[Git Hub Link](https://github.com/ericallenpaul/IdentityFramework)

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: The error is: The type 'IdentityFramework.Service.ApplicationDbContext' must be convertible to the 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext` inherits from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext` as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which leads me to wonder if you are possibly using a prior version of Identity Framework and  `AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework6.IdentityDbContext`?

Comment: I am using .Net Core 2.1.3. IDesignTimeDbContextFactory inherits from DbContext as well. What I need is a version of IDesignTimeDbContextFactory which can inherit from IdentityDbContext--which apparently doesn't exist. Guess I need to think of another way to solve the problem.

Comment: `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` does not inherit from `DbContext`, it takes a type parameter that must inherit from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`.  What the error message is telling you is your `ApplicationDbContext` does not inherit from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext` which is why I'm suggesting you're using the non-.net-core version of Identity Framework.  Right click on `IdentityDbContext`, go to definition, and view the namespace.  Is it `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`?

Comment: OK, that was totally it and now I feel dumb. Thanks!